# How do I convert a List with String(number) entries into a List with numbers that works with numpy.dot (dotproduct)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My current problem is doing the dotproduct but my list

```
            label= list2 = example[4]
            doc  = list2 = example[0:4]
            a=train[0]
            print(a)
            >> ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', '0 ']



    def train(self, train):
    for i in range(self.N):
        for example in train:
            label= list2 = map(float,example[4])
            doc  = list2 = map(float,example[0:4])
            prediction = np.dot(doc, self.weights)
            if prediction != label:
                self.weights += self.lr * (label - prediction) * doc
            else:
                self.weights = self.weights
    return self.weights
```

The problem here is

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'float'
```

If I remove the map float on doc and label I get

```
  TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'.
```

I know my list contains strings but does anyone know how to convert this string so it can operate the calculations in my class for example * or numpy.dot

import numpy as np
def read_iris(filename):

```
with open (filename) as f:
    linelist=list()
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("Iris-setosa", "0").replace("Iris-versicolor", "1").replace("Iris-virginica", "2")
        if "\n" in line:
            line = line.replace("\n", " ") 
            for element in line.split(','):
                linelist.append(element)
            data = [ linelist [i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(linelist), 5) ]
    return data

def split_data(data):
return tuple(data[1:]), tuple(data[::5])

data = read_iris("iris.data")
train, test = split_data(data)

import numpy as np
class MCP():

def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250, learning_rate=0.1):
    self.f = features
    self.l = labels
    self.N = epochs
    self.lr = learning_rate
    self.weights = self.initialize_weights() 

def initialize_weights(self):
    weights = np.zeros(self.f)
    return weights

def train(self, train):
    for i in range(self.N):
        for example in train:
            label= np.array(example[4])
            doc  = np.array(example[0:4])
            prediction = np.dot(doc, self.weights)
            if prediction != label:
                self.weights += self.lr * (label - prediction) * doc
            else:
                self.weights = self.weights
    return self.weights
```

mcp = MCP()
mcp.initialize_weights()

mcp.train(train)

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'



5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

That's how the iris looks like and I think I'm converting this iris wrong since the text wants me to 1. Reads the iris file into memory. 2. filename: string. The filename 3. Returns:
        list of lists (one for each data point). Inner lists contain a numpy array (the features)
            and an integer (iris type).

Could someone help me figure out how to transform the iris into a list containing a array for the 4 floats and then a integer for the Iris-test

Comment: Why are you using `map()`? Can you share your code and data? I imagine that there’s some refactoring to do. What do you understand from those two error messages? Speaking of, can you include the entire messages?

Comment: My problem is the list containing strings thats why I tried to convert it but it doesnt work. That's why im asking for alternatives

Comment: In python 3, `map` is unevaluated, like a generator.  You have to evaluate it, with something like `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @RandomDog Which list? Please remember that (as far as I know) no one on Stack Overflow can read minds. Also, the formatting of your appears to be broken in a few spots, I would double check it if I were you.

Comment: You should be able to convert a list of strings to a numeric array with: `doc  = np.array(example[0:4], 'float')`.  You don't need to use the `map(float, ...)` expression.

Comment: I forgot to ask, what do you understand from that error message? Isn’t it rather clear cut?

Comment: I certainly understand that the types I'm using to perform a dotproduct are not working together